# How do I create a stored procedure in MySQL that will select data and insert new values?

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, parameters, max

Hi I am trying to create a database that will check out document numbers per project. I am trying to keep the db server action limited to stored procedures.

The numbering system goes

XXXX-YY-ZZZZ

XXXX is the job number
YY is the document type table reference
ZZZZ is the document specific number and increments from 1 up for each type in each job...

Because of the numbering system, I can not use an auto incremented column... That would be nice... I would have to generate a table for each document type, for each job... unless anyone sees anything I do not?  I am pretty new at this, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have for my procedure that I am having issues with.

`DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ADD_NEW_DOC$$
CREATE DEFINER=RMDNA@localhost PROCEDURE ADD_NEW_DOC(IN in_job INT, IN in_type VARCHAR(2), IN in_name VARCHAR(32), IN in_desc VARCHAR(512))
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(doc_id) INTO @highnum FROM Doc_Entries WHERE job_id = in_job AND doc_type_ID = in_type$$
    IF @highnum = null THEN SET @newnum = 1$$
    ELSE SET @newnum = @highnum + 1$$
    END IF$$
    insert into Doc_Entries (job_id, doc_type_ID, doc_id, doc_name, doc_desc) values (in_job, in_type, @newnum, in_name, in_desc)$$
    SELECT @newnum$$
END$$
DELIMITER ;`

and the error I am getting is:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

UPDATE:

My attempt has refined...

`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ADD_NEW_DOC;
DELIMITER // 
CREATE DEFINER=RMDNA@localhost PROCEDURE ADD_NEW_DOC(IN in_job INT, IN in_type VARCHAR(2), IN in_name VARCHAR(32), IN in_desc VARCHAR(512)) 
BEGIN 
    SELECT MAX(doc_id) INTO @highnum FROM Doc_Entries WHERE job_id = in_job AND doc_type_ID = in_type;
    IF (@highnum is null) THEN SET @newnum = 1;
    ELSE SET @newnum = @highnum + 1;
    END IF; 
    insert into Doc_Entries (job_id, doc_type_ID, doc_id, doc_name, doc_desc) values (in_job, in_type, @newnum, in_name, in_desc);
    SELECT @newnum; 
END// 
DELIMITER ;`

Working good now. Learned how to use delimiter properly and fixed a few things that then became obvious.

Comment: There's so much here that I can see, that you can't, I'm not sure where to begin. But The stored procedure is the least of your problems. Perhaps you're trying to run before you can walk?

Comment: I learn by doing. I am happy to hear any specific criticisms you may have.

Comment: @Strawberry I would appreciate pointers or even a nudge in the right direction. To tell me how much better than me, you are at this is hardly productive.

Comment: Fundamentally, I think you're confusing the concepts of data storage and data display. You need to store multiple pieces of information (principally,  job number and document type) which belong in separate columns. You also need to store some way of identifying the sequence (the z component). Contrary to what you say, in a MyISAM table, this *can* be held in an AI column although, personally, I don't think an AI column should ever be part of a public key. So, my preference would be to allow the application code to calculate the sequence, or do something with MAX(sequence) inside a transaction.

Comment: @Strawberry That gives me quite a lot to read up on. Thank you. I really appreciate the input, being a neophyte.